# mapKit Apple: Bug with places' names and no focus map on user

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, mapkit

I try to go from VC1 on VC2 with map by button1 through segue, and It has to focus pin on my location in the center of map and it has bug. it doesn't focus on user, but if I press button 2, go back and press button 1, it focuses on user. And I can't understand where is I need to fix it.

And the last bug: if I set huge value of regionInMeters, for e.g. 10000m, and I zoom, it shows names of places, streets with bug(image) in both cases, when I try to use this method with user. If I set low - 500, it shows correct close in these cases, but just location around user, if I switch there in another city and zoom in, it still will have this bug. And the same story with focus on place. On huge height - country names, cities, rivers are correct everywhere [image].

```
let annotationIdentifire = "annotationIdentifire"
let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
let regionInMeters = 500.00
var incomeSegueIdentifire = ""
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    addressLabel.text = ""
    mapView.delegate = self
    setupMapView()
    checkLocationServices()
} 
private func checkLocationServices(){

    if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {
        setupLocationManager()
        checkLocationAuthorization()
} else{...}
private func checkLocationAuthorization() {
    switch CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() {
    case .authorizedWhenInUse:
        mapView.showsUserLocation = true
        if incomeSegueIdentifire == "getAddress" { showUserLocation() }
        break
//other cases
}
```

Also I have another button2 with segue on VC1 which opens VC2 with map and it focuses on place, with address, which I set, and in this case I have button3 on map, which focuses on me correct:

```
  @IBAction func centerViewInUserLocation() {
    showUserLocation()
}
```

There is method which I use to focus on user.

```
private func showUserLocation() {
    if let location = locationManager.location?.coordinate {
        let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: location,
                                        latitudinalMeters: regionInMeters,
                                        longitudinalMeters: regionInMeters)
        mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)
    }
}
```

Value of incomeSegueIdentifire I set in another class

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
         guard let identifire = segue.identifier, let mapVC = segue.destination as? MapViewController else { return }
    mapVC.incomeSegueIdentifire = identifire
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I din't find how to fix bug with places' names, but I fixed the main bug(when open map by segue it has to focus on user, but it's not).

I get mistake:Could not retrieve region info. And tried to find the answer for this case, but didn't find. Found couple cases with answers about this mistake and there said, that code is OK, but still mistake, and the main answer/advice - try to run it on your real device, may be it's correct, I don't have iphone/ipad. But for simulator I fixed it by calling this method asynchronously with delay, and it works for me)

```
private func checkLocationAuthorization() {
    switch CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() {
    case .authorizedWhenInUse:
        mapView.showsUserLocation = true
        if incomeSegueIdentifire == "getAddress" { DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1) {
            self.showUserLocation()
            }
        }
        //other cases
    }
}
```

But still, if you have any ideas with these issues, I'll be glad to know))